# Pixela API will not let me create a graph

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to do an assignment with the Pixela API and it allows me to create an account, but when I make the call to create a graph it keeps telling me my username doesn't exist or my token is wrong, I set them both as constants up at the top and definitely didn't change them in between the calls so I'm not sure what to do? I figured I'd ask on here if anyone can help before just skipping the assignment

```
import requests

USERNAME = "hoods"
TOKEN = "subarupython!!!"

pixela_endpoint = "https://pixe.la/v1/users"
graph_endpoint = f"https://pixe.la/v1/users/{USERNAME}/graphs"
user_params = {
    "token": TOKEN,
    "username": USERNAME,
    "agreeTermsOfService": "yes",
    "notMinor": "yes"
}
#Create user account
# response = requests.post(url=pixela_endpoint,json=user_params)
# print(response.text)

graph_config = {
    "id": "graph1",
    "name": "training",
    "unit": "hours",
    "type": "int",
    "color": "sora"
}

header = {
    "X_USER_TOKEN": TOKEN
}

graph_response = requests.post(headers=header, url=graph_endpoint, json=graph_config)
print(graph_response.text)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the underscores in "X_USER_TOKEN" need to be hyphens. I am prepared to be made fun of.

Comment: Nothing wrong with finding the issue yourself, in my opinion. Probably the best way to learn.